# Value in a multiline TextInput field not fully rendering. React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a multiline TextInput field that I am trying to set a multiple line value to.

my text input is rendered like this:

```
textInput () {
  return (
    <TextInput
        style={styles.bioBox}
        onChangeText={this.onBioChange}
        value={this.state.bio}
        maxLength={255}
        multiline={true}/>
  )
}
```

Essentially it's a short bio, and I want the user to have the ability to edit it. To do this, I am trying to set the value of the TextInput to the bio, which I fetch from my db.

The initial state for bio is set in the constructor as "Loading...":

```
this.state = {
  text: "",
  bio:"Loading...",
  picture: "http://sierrafire.cr.usgs.gov/images/loading.gif"
}
```

and then I fetch the bio and set it like so:

```
fetch(urlPath, queryObject)
  .then(function(res){
    result = JSON.parse(res._bodyText)
    that.setState({  //set that=this in the constructor
      id: result.id,
      first_name : result.first_name,
      name: result.name,
      age: result.age || 'null',
      picture: result.picture,
      gender: result.gender,
      preference: result.preference,
      bio: result.bio,
      headline: result.headline 
    })
  })
```

It more or less works the way it should. Initially the textbox renders "Loading...", then once the fetch is complete it sets the state and causes a rerender with the new value set to whatever I got back from my query.

The weird part is this - only the first line of the new value of the TextInput appears in the simulator. However, once the user clicks inside the text input and types something, it all immediately pops into view.

Additionally, I have a character countdown on the bottom of this box that lets users know how many characters they have left. When this happens, before clicking in the TextInput, this component has reference to the actual length, and renders accordingly. So if I have a text input value over multiple lines, for example:

```
I'm an amateur sailor from NZ.
My favorite color is blue.
```

Only "I'm an amateur sailor from NZ" will show on the page, but the character countdown will calculate based on the length of both sentences. And only after the user clicks inside the TextInput and types, will "My favorite color is blue." render.

In case this is relevant, my styles look like this:

```
bioBox:{
    flex: 1,
    paddingLeft: 5,
    height: 100, 
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 2,
    marginRight: 50,
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    fontSize: 15,
    fontFamily: "HelveticaNeue-Light",
},
```

Comment: I have tried trimming the input to see if perhaps the text input was having trouble with new lines by setting my state in the .then after my fetch thusly:


    bio: result.bio.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"")


It didn't work.

Comment: I've also done a .split('\n') to see if there were even any new lines in the string I was getting back, but it doesn't look like it.

Comment: I added a setTimeout inside my componentWillMount to force a rerender. It did change the state and force a rerender, butthe prolbem persisted, and even if I added a setState that would change the bio (the multiLine input I am having problems with) it will again only show the first line.

Comment: RIght now I'm trying to see if I can render the bio inside a <TouchableHighlight> as a <Text>. It pulls everything onto the page which is good, but obviously being Text and not TextInput it's not editable. My idea is to give the TouchableHighlight and onPress function that somehow replaced the TouchableHighlight with a TextInput. Though as I think through this, even if I get that to work, there's no reason to believe the TextInput will render it's multiline value correctly.

Comment: Another idea I have explored but may still be worth checking into was setting a property of autoFocus to True, so that it would focus on that spot, and then somehow having the app "use" that focus to "type" an empty space into the TextInput. Essentially I'm trying to figure out if there is a way I can get the app to recreate the user behavior that causes the TextInput to render correctly.

Comment: Hi Brian, did you find a solution ? thanks !